# Use `mdfind` for a date range on OS X

Tags: macos, spotlight

I can't figure this out. How can I use `mdfind` on OS X to find all photos with creation date between say March 10th, 2008 and March 15th, 2008?

using `mdfind 'kMDItemFSCreationDate = 2008-03-10 12:30:56 +1100'` is too specific and I don't know how to simplify and broaden the search.

Comment: Melchior, are you talking about spotlight on Mac or iPhone/iPad? Please reply with `@JohnRamos` so I can further help you.

Comment: @JohnRamos Hi John. I edited the original question with more detail. It relates to `mdfind` on OS X. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To simplify and broaden the search you may use operands like >, <, >=, <= or line up several attribute values with `&&`.

To solve the above mentioned example you can use two different creation times and an item kind:

```
mdfind 'kMDItemFSCreationDate < $time.iso(2008-03-15T23:59:59) && kMDItemFSCreationDate > $time.iso(2008-03-10T00:00:00) && kMDItemKind = *image'
```