# mdfind after x time today?

Tags: terminal, spotlight

I've read up [this man page](https://ss64.com/osx/mdfind.html) and this [spotlight metadata attributes documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/SpotlightQuery/Concepts/QueryFormat.html) but still cannot hit the nail with the query to show files added after 23:30 hours.

Heck, I can't even list files added today (now yesterday as I write this it's 00 hours):

```
Downloads[0:01] $ mdfind -onlyin . 'kMDItemDateAdded = $time.yesterday'
Downloads[0:02] $
```

(also tried `mdfind -onlyin . 'kMDItemDateAdded = "$time.yesterday"'`)

When I do have files added a few hours ago:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`'kMDItemDateAdded = $time.yesterday'` returns nothing because `$time.yesterday` is the exact time of yesterday at 00:00:00. So for dates it is getter to use comparisons, like this:

```
mdfind -onlyin . 'kMDItemDateAdded >= $time.yesterday && kMDItemDateAdded < $time.today'
```

This gets all files added after or at yesterday 00:00:00 and before today 00:00:00.

The `man mdfind` is particularly brief and unhelpful regarding queries.

Though not for a single day, this [Use `mdfind` for a date range on OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/247298/use-mdfind-for-a-date-range-on-os-x) expands a little on date ranges.

Alternatively, if you know the date of yesterday you can pose the search without explicitly using kMD metadata. Like this:

```
mdfind -onlyin . added:15/6/2023
```

It uses your locale to work out the data format you are using.